# Is there a way to change only certain parentheses to the underbar?

Tags: tcl

I want to change to

> [number] -> _number_

and leave the rest as it is.
In the example below, only three were created, but there are more than 100 in one line in my script.

**before**

```
[list [get_pins [change $ate2[7]]] [get_pins $ut2_mi[24]]]  -to [get_pins $abc[2]]
```

**after**

```
[list [get_pins [change $ate2_7_]] [get_pins $ut2_mi_24_]]  -to [get_pins $abc_2_]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very straight-forward task for `regsub`, assuming your *number* is just a sequence of one or more digits:

```
set str {[list [get_pins [change $ate2[7]]] [get_pins $ut2_mi[24]]] -to [get_pins $abc[2]]}
regsub -all {\[(\d+)\]} $str {_\1_}
```

Result: [list [get_pins [change $ate2_7_]] [get_pins $ut2_mi_24_]] -to [get_pins $abc_2_]

If you also want to handle negative integers or floating point numbers, that's going to be more challenging.